# Control default action in ASP on Enter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This may be an easy question for you guys. 
I have a web form with several buttons and only one textbox. When I enter a value in the textbox and press enter the method gets executed that is wired to the first top left button. I need to control what button's method gets executed (in this case it is a button in a whole different location that does db query).
I tried to alter tab index to have my desired button the lowest and I tried to pass focus to my desired button on page_load (like I would have done in Win Forms) but still if I enter text in textbox and hit eneter, the top left button's method gets executed.
I could put conditions in execution of top left button's method but that would be a workaround not a solution. So how do I control that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET form has a [defaultbutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that specifies which button is clicked when ENTER is pressed. Just specify your button ID there. E.g.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="MyDbQueryButton">
```

Comment: You should be able to always access the form programmaticaly via `this.Form.DefaultButton`